# How to execute a script in VSTS

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-artifacts

I have few scripts example (xcode.sh) which is in the mac agent. I would like to execute the script with 2 input Arguments. The user does not know the path to this script. How can i achieve this from VSTS Task

Say the script has to be executed like \usr\local\xcode "aaa" "bbb"

In Bamboo i do this with Executable and choose the executable in the Task

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a Shell Script task that can specify Script path.

If the script file is in the current repository of build (Get source), you can click … button to select file, otherwise you need to specify the path manually.

Regarding arguments, you can specify it in Argument input box.

[image]

Update:

You can custom build task to define an input with picklist type, simple sample:

```
 "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "ConnectedServiceName",
            "type": "connectedService:AzureRM",
            "label": "Azure subscription",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "required": true,
            "helpMarkDown": "Select the Azure Resource Manager subscription"
        },
        {
            "name": "Action",
            "type": "pickList",
            "label": "Action",
            "required": false,
            "helpMarkDown": "Action to be performed on the App Service. You can Start, Stop, Restart, Slot swap or Install site extensions for an Azure App Service",
            "defaultValue": "Swap Slots",
            "options": {
                "Swap Slots": "Swap Slots",
                "Start Azure App Service": "Start App Service",
                "Stop Azure App Service": "Stop App Service",
                "Restart Azure App Service": "Restart App Service",
                "Install Extensions": "Install Extensions"
            }
        }
}
```

Regarding custom build task, you can refer to [Add a build task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-build-task)

You can retrieve the data from server (e.g. web api) and populate to that input box.

Some threads to bind source.

[How to display “Area path” in VSTS build task input PickList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801086/how-to-display-area-path-in-vsts-build-task-input-picklist)

[Use the ServiceEndpoinr.Uri as/in the SourceDefinition.Endpoint](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/973)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. The Script Path is not known to the users . It should probably display in the dropdown and use just choose one of them.

Comment: @KarthikeyanKulasekaran I updated my answer. You can custom build task, the built-in tasks don't meet your requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback .I will try this