# using http post/get method to get data from service running on third server in tfs build task

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines-build-task

In a customized build task, how can I  use http post/get method to get data from service running on a third server?

In a build task like below screenshot, I want to get populate the dropdown list from a third server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99U1G.png)

At this time, I can only populate the dropdown list from a static list in the task.json file like below:

"inputs": [

```
    {"name":"CompanyDepartments",



       "type":"pickList",



       "label":"Company Departments",



       "defaultValue":"",



       "required":true,



       "helpMarkDown":"",



       "groupName":"group1",



       "options":{



           "0":"Developers",



           "1":"Admin",



           "2":"Requirements"}



   },
```

Comment: Hi Dan, any update on this, have you figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved, you could define **sourceDefinitions** to call service (e.g. REST API) to get necessary data and bind data to corresponding picklist in **dataSourceBindings**.

Suggest doing the following:

> - Create a custom endpoint for relic service
> - Add a dataSource in the endpoint corresponding to the REST URL to    query applications
> - Add a resultSelector within the dataSource to parse out the Name from    each of the appName json element
> - Add an endpoint input to your task
> - Add a dataSourceBinding from your task that references the dataSource    you defined in the endpoint
>
> You can refer to how drop down for Azure storage accounts has been
>   added to Azure File Copy task as an example:
>
> https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureFileCopy/task.json

You could also take a look at this tutorial--[**Service Endpoints in VSTS**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/service-endpoints): it shows how a build task which defines 2 properties: The service endpoint & a picklist which has values populated from the REST endpoint data source.

Some more threads to bind source for your reference:

- [How to display "Area path" in VSTS build task input PickList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801086/how-to-display-area-path-in-vsts-build-task-input-picklist)
- [Use the ServiceEndpoinr.Uri as/in the SourceDefinition.Endpoint](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/973)